# Are isentropic closed rigid thermodynamic systems also isolated?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

$\newcommand{\d}{\, \mathrm d}$Currently it seems to me that isentropic closed rigid thermodynamic systems have to be also isolated. Is this correct?

The reason why it seems to me like this is the following.

The energy-based fundamental equation is: $$\d U = T\d S - P\d V + \sum \mu_{i} \d n_{i}$$. 
Because the system is closed, $\d n=0$. 
Because the system is rigig, $\d V=0$. 
And because the system is isentropic, $\d S=0$.
Thus $\d U=0$, which means there is no energy change possible. And if there is no exchange of energy possible between the system and the surrounding, then the system is essentially isolated. And therefore also thermally isolated.

Is this argument correct, or am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: Hi Jadzia and welcome to Physics.SE! Please see [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) help post to learn how to write your equations in a way nicer way i.e. in $\LaTeX$, in order to improve legibility. I did it for you this time but it would be better if you did it by yourself in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Hello gonenc, thank you very much for your comment and the improvements. I will read your suggested help post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesnt necessarily mean that. In general, the internal energy is of the form,$$d U = Td S - Pd V + \sum \mu_{i} d n_{i} + J.dx$$

where $J$ refers to a generalised force and $dx$ to a generalised displacement, and even $-P.dV$ can be written as product of a generalised force and displacement with pressure serving as the former and volume serving as the latter. Suppose the system is immersed in a magnetizing intensity $H$ and the system develops a magnetization $M$. Then the net magnetic field is given by

$$ B = \mu_0(H + M)$$

and the work done excluding the mutual field energy is given by

$$ \delta W = - MdB$$

which can now be included in the expression for internal energy as

$$d U = Td S - Pd V + \sum \mu_{i} d n_{i} - M.dB$$

In general, there are many other possible scenarios too where you can prove that isentropic closed rigid thermodynamic systems are not totally isolated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually I was thinking about simple systems, where in general only pressure-volume work, chemical work (by transition via the boundary) and heat transfer by conduction can occur. Should I edit my first post with the question accordingly?

Comment: @Jadzia i think your post is alright and shouldn't be edited..and in answer to your question, if only PV and chemical work is there, then you are right..

Comment: @ Bruce Lee: Thanks again for your answer. 

If the system would not be in equilibrium yet, and the system/process is still isentropic, closed and rigid, then the entropy can only be assured to remain constant by changing the energy of the system via heat transfer, in which case the system would not be isolated. Is that correct too?

Comment: i am talking only about the equilibrium cases... in case equilibrium is not yet obtained, then the entropy of a closed system doesn't necessarily remain constant..if you consider systems at equilibrium only, then the entropy of a closed system is fixed and further heat addition changes the entropy..